# How can i pass jTextField value from one class to another when clicking a jButton?

Tags: java, netbeans, jtextfield

Greetings from jamaica,

I'm having trouble with a netbeans java project. I have two separate classes: A gui class called **MainJFrame.java** and another class called **main.java**.

In the MainJFrame form i have a jTextField and a jbutton. How can i pass the jtextfield value to the main.java class by clicking the jbutton?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You keep a reference to an instance of your Main class in the MainJFrame class.
2. You define an `ActionListener` for your JButton.
3. In this ActionListener, you get the value of the JTextField with `JTextField.getText()`
4. And you call a method of Main class on the instance you kept in first step with the text as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

one possible solution would be to create a third class which handles the communication.
 There you would have to register the main.java and pass it to MainJFrame.java.

For Example

```
public class handler {
    public static main myClass = new main;

    public static main getClass() {
        retunr myClass;
    }

}
```

Your JFrameMain should containt a new variable

```
private main mainClass = handler.getClass();
```

Your onClicklistener should now voi dthe method from your mainClass which gets the text.

```
mainClass.setText(textFromJText);
```

Hope i could help you.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was not finished when you answered. So I edited it. Now it is complete and I hope it helps you.